# Get data from service android

Tags: android, android-activity, service, fragment

My app start a service (and bound it to an activity) in `onCreate` method. When my `MainActivity` start load fragments. I need get data from `Service` to initialize content of fragments when fragments load into `MainActivity`.

The problem is, the service reference is null in `onCreate` and i cant get data from service when app load.

Any suggestion helps me. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post the code snippet , where you are starting service and loading fragments for better understanding, so that i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a handler in your service.

After service had loaded the data you need.

Send a message to your activity or fragment and refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into service calling demos or examples its not a big thing you need to call service and handle its callback and by the time you need to show progress  wheel and as soon as your Activity or fragments gets callback of service call you can render appropriate view with data